# Covering a $8\times 8$ chessboard with dominoes without placing any domino over another.

Tags: combinatorics

> In how many ways can $8\times 8$ chessboard be with dominoes without placing any domino over another.

I have this problem in my mind since I read colouring proofs. This question has been haunting me since then. Everytime I try to do something about it, I end up finding myself in a distressed condition without any progress towards the solution. I tried searching about it in many books and even in Google but could not find anything. Is it that, this question has no solution yet or there exists a solution and I am not able to find it. Please help me if there exists some solution. I cannot keep on searching more on this. I know about combinatorics till pre-college level and have done several IMO level problems.

Answer (score 3):

The number of domino tilings of an $m\times n$ grid is [tabulated](https://oeis.org/A099390) at the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, and a general formula is given there.

See also [Number of different ways of filling $N \times 4$ rectangle with Dominoes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482944/number-of-different-ways-of-filling-n-times-4-rectangle-with-dominoes).

Number of domino tilings of a square board tabulated, with formula, [here](https://oeis.org/A004003).

And there's always [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino_tiling) where the formula is written out nicely.